# delaying angular directives

Tags: angularjs, directive

I have a common AJS service that is consumed by a custom AJS directive.
I need to hold my directive until a promise is resolved within the service. 
From what I have read this is done through the directivecontroller but I have not seen any examples other than for route.

How do I delay my directive until the service promise has been resolved?

[image]

Comment: Could you clarify what part of the directive? Directives are very versatile, in that you can modify the compile/link/controller phases, and the answer may depend on it!

Comment: Great picture, although it might be helpful to post the code from a minimal directive, showing what needs to be delayed.

Answer (score 0):

I have a similar situation. My directive has to wait for a third-party library to complete some DOM manipulations. I use a retry function to check every 50 milliseconds to see if the DOM element I need exists yet.

In the directive:

```
Utils.retry(function() { return !!$(selector)[0]; }, 50, 10).then(function() {         
  doSomethingInterestingWith($(selector));
});
```

The retry function (I define this in a Utils service):

```
var retry = function(fn, interval, maxTries) {
  var result, deferred;
  deferred = $q.defer();

  // if we get a result, return it
  result = fn();
  if (result !== false) { deferred.resolve(result); }

  else {
    // if we've run out of tries, return false
    if (maxTries) { maxTries -= 1; }
    if (maxTries === 0) { deferred.reject('timed out'); }

    // otherwise try again after interval
    else {
      $timeout(function() {
        deferred.resolve(retry(fn, interval, maxTries));
      }, interval);
    }
  }

  return deferred.promise;
};

Utils.retry = retry;
```

See the [plunk](http://plnkr.co/edit/ckS4wR?p=preview) for a working example.